# Django Autocomplete with Anaconda in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to get autocompletion working in Sublime Text 3 via the Anaconda plug-in. So far I've been successful getting autocompletion working with the standard python libraries but not for Django.

My sublime project file looks like this:

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "follow_symlinks": true,
      "path": "."
    }
  ],

  "settings": {
    "python_interpreter": "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/project/bin/python",
    "suppress_word_completions": true,
    "extra_paths":
    [
        "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
    ],
    "anaconda_debug": true,
  },

  "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name":"Virtualenv 2.7 Project",
            "shell_cmd": "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/project/bin/python -u \"$file\"",
            "path": "/Users/jamiehush/.virtualenvs/project/bin",
            "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
            "selector": "source.python"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm also running "subl" from a terminal while inside a virtual environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need any special `extra_path` to make autocompleting work with Django. Nothing make Django special, anaconda should be able to autocomplete whatever is visible by your configured python interpreter.

Make sure that the virtual environment in `project` has a copy of Django installed on it. If you have `virtualenwrapper` installed should be as easy as:

$ workon project

$ python

```
import django
```

If you have Django in your virtualenv, is possible that the anaconda JsonServer was started before you installed the library and it's not able to see it. Restart your Sublime Text 3 and try again.

In case that you still have problems, send an email to the anaconda's mailing list or open an issue in the Github project (https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/issues) indicating your operating system, ST3 build and Python version that you are using so we can help you further.