# How to have Anaconda autocomplete Django?

Tags: django, autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I am trying to switch from PyCharm to ST3 but I can't get the Anaconda plugin to autocomplete Django stuff. For example, within a model:

`content = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')`

Anaconda can't autocomplete this. When I type `models.Tex`, it doesn't offer any autocompletion.

I'm using a virtualenv inside my Django project within `.venv/` (on Mac) and tried setting the `"python_interpreter"` config key to the interpreter within the virtualenv. It didn't help. I have looked at [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661414/django-autocomplete-with-anaconda-in-sublime-text-3) but it didn't help either.

What can I try?

Comment: I just did a fresh install on Ubuntu and installed Anaconda. I saved a project settings file (Project > Save Project As...) and told Anaconda to look for my virtual env python interpreter as in http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/anaconda_settings/. Navigate to the directory and start sublime from there. After a few seconds it should work.